# oledata.mso, image001.emz - What do I do to actually open this?

Tags: email, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I received an email from someone I know (and expected) containing 2 attachments. I was expecting a PowerPoint file, but instead received a "image001.emz" and "oledata.mso" file instead. The oledata.mso file seems to be the big file (6 MB) as apposed to the image001.emz file (2 KB).

I can not for the life of me figure out how to open the MSO file. I have tried the following:

- Microsoft PowerPoint 2007
- Microsoft Outlook 2007
- Microsoft PowerPoint 2010
- Microsoft Outlook 2010
- Microsoft Visio 2007
- Microsoft Visio 2010
- OpenOffice (Latest Version)
- 7-Zip (I thought maybe it was a special zipped up file)
- I uploaded it to Google Docs
- I attempted to open it through my Blackberry (OS6) device

Nothing seems to work. What can I do to open this attachment??

Comment: Ask the sender to zip and then attach the zipped Power point file in an email to you.

Comment: A Powerpoint 2007/2010 PPTX/PPSX, etc file is actually a zip that contains a bunch of XML files, images and some other odds and ends that vary depending on the contents of the original powerpoint presentation. OLEData.MSO is one of those files.  The EMZ file is a preview image of one of the slides, most likely.  It sounds as though they've managed to unzip and send you portions of the presentation file.  Can't imagine what posessed them to do this, but other than the EMZ as described by woliveirajr, you can't do anything with the files.  Ask them to stop dinking and just send you the PPTX .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this site:
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/emzfile.htm

> An EMZ file is just a compressed version of an EMF file, a kind of graphics format. You can open the file by inserting it in any Microsoft Office program as an image or you can extract the EMF file from the EMZ file and then open the EMF file in an image editing program.